# remove a drupal select list option from a node add form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook-form-alter

Can i remove a `drupal` select list option from a node add form, but will stay on  edit form having that option selected using `hook_form_alter`.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, In your hook_form_alter, change the '#type' from 'select' to 'hidden'. And set the '#value' to the value you want.
You could also unset() the '#options' but I don't think it will matter as the hidden type should ignore it.
This should be enough to do what you want I think